# What is the processing order of input files in mapreduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I use  **FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(input1), new Path(input2));** to add two input files to the mapreduce program and assume that the program will process input2 when completing processing input1.

but when i change the order, it give the same result.why?(the process of the input2 is premised on completely processing input1).

```
public static class CalculateResultMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
    private final static IntWritable k = new IntWritable();
    private final static Text v = new Text();
    private final static Map<Integer, List<Cooccurrence>> matrix = 
            new HashMap<Integer, List<Cooccurrence>>();

    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] tokens = Recommend.DELIMITER.split(value.toString());
        String[] v1 = tokens[0].split(":");
        String[] v2 = tokens[1].split(":");

        //processing input1
        if(v1.length > 1) {
            int itemID1 = Integer.parseInt(v1[0]);
            int itemID2 = Integer.parseInt(v1[1]);
            int num = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            CalculateResult_4 c = new CalculateResult_4();
            List<Cooccurrence> list = null;
            if(!matrix.containsKey(itemID1)) {
                list = new ArrayList<Cooccurrence>();
            } else {
                list = matrix.get(itemID1);
            }
            list.add(c.new Cooccurrence(itemID1, itemID2, num));
            matrix.put(itemID1, list);
        }

        //processing input2
        if(v2.length > 1) {
            int itemID = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            int userID = Integer.parseInt(v2[0]);
            double pref = Double.parseDouble(v2[1]);
            k.set(userID);
            for(Cooccurrence co : matrix.get(itemID)) {
                v.set(co.getItemID2() + "," + pref * co.getNum());
                context.write(k, v);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is probably acting on the two files simultaneously (applying maps to all files, as a map task finishes, shuffle/sort/reduce starts).  You give up a lot of determinism (in terms of order of execution) when doing MR (or any parallel computation for that matter).

Comment: @TravisJ Does it mean I can't programme in that way? So if i want to use input1 as a map to be referenced and then process input2, what way should I choose?

Comment: The only way I know of to force something like that is to create two seperate jobs (run MR on the first file, then run it later on the second).  This will be expensive.  Are you trying to perform two different computations on the files? or use the output of one file to determine how to compute the next?  Why do they have to be processed in a specific order?

Comment: @TravisJ Yep.I am just attempting to use the output of one file to determine how to compute the next.It performs different computations on the files.My confusion is that the second file need to be processed using the map, and the map must be consist of all the information of the first file, otherwise the result will not be accurate.Because the map need to be in memory, i put both two computations in one MR.In other words, is MR not suit for this kind of situation？

Comment: MR might be effective... certainly writing to disk and then reading back in will hurt performance significantly.  Have you looked at Apache-Spark?  It uses the Hadoop filesystem and can handle MR (in parallel) but also has a much richer set of features (and it doesn't write to disk unless you make it).

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks a lot. I will consider another solution using Spark:)